# Populate html dynamically as backend runs in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am looking to dynamically populate results using flask and jQuery.

I have a program that runs a long series of tasks in a backend function  appends the results to a list. Is there a way through ajax/jquery to dynamically add results to the page (say every few seconds) until the backend has finished running (Almost how a website like Travelocity dynamically adds flights to the page as it finds them). Currently, I cannot understand how to update results using ajax while the backend is still running (it waits until it is complete before returning any results).

My hypothetical example:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'Begin Running Backend',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
             while(**BACKEND IS RUNNING**){
                    $("#samplediv").text(data.current_results);
                   }
                },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("FAILED");
        }
     });
```

While in the backend:

```
@app.route("/test",methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    run_script() #In this script, a for loop is adding results to a list
    return jsonify(results=list)
```

Comment: You need to fundamentally change how you're doing things.  Without getting into websockets, the HTTP request response cycle is a one time deal.  Your server will respond one time to one request.  So to have something update continuously (without websockets), you'd need to write something that requests the results from the server, then the server sends back like a "request started" signal, then your client periodically asks the server for any results it's gathered so far, until on one of those requests, the server gives a "no more results" signal. Travelocity probably uses websockets.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop is not necessary here, as you will not receive a `success` callback until the server responds favorably.

The biggest issue you may be encoutering, however, is a possible `timeout` due to the long response time:

You can add the following to give it up to 1 minutes:

```
timeout: 60000
```

Then in your success function, start with `logging` out the results:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

You do not need to pause the client side in this way with a `while` loop.